# How to get selection service in plugin activator

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I need to somehow get reference on selection service in activator. I tried this:

```
IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IWorkbenchWindow ww = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
ww.getSelectionService().addSelectionListener(new GlobalSelectionListener());
```

But `ww` is always `null`. I haven't found another code to get selection service reference. This code works only if Eclepse is fully initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you're invoking getActiveWorkbenchWindow() on a Display thread in order to get a non-null return.

Try:

```
final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
workbench.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    IWorkbenchWindow window = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    if (window != null) {
      // do something
    }
  }
});
```

That example's from the javadoc from org.eclipse.ui.IStartup.  If you'd like your code to be executed as soon as possible after the workbench is initialized, you should consider extending the [org.eclipse.ui.startup](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_startup.html) extension point.